# Inaccurate GPS location

Tags: android, gps

I am reading my coordinates every 20 seconds or 10 meters an displaying them with a Toast. At the same time I read the GPS values from the notifications panel in the system bar. The values are not the same.

Altitude is in my program always around 560 metres and in the notifications panel 430 (430 is correct). I get similar errors with lat. and long. The error is not due to difference in time. The Toast shows the values onLocationChange. I used the code based on [this project](http://hejp.co.uk/android/android-gps-example/) and rely only on the GPS sensor.

Why is this so? Does anybody know why I'm getting different values?

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet showing how you're constructing your notifications, and when you're showing the toasts?